# where does spring load the auto configuration files from

Tags: spring-boot

I have read some tutorial on old version of spring boot.

https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/auto-config-mechanism.html

> The boot configuration classes are loaded from
> spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring.factories
> (in the file, search for the key
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration)

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.4.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories It has "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration"

My understanding is that spring loads/runs all these files defined by EnableAutoConfiguration in spring.factories. If the @Conditional* matches, the bean will be created.

But in the last 2.x version, there is no such property EnableAutoConfiguration
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.7.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories

where does spring load the auto configuration files from?

**Updated**:

I found them here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.7.4/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports

Spring Boot 2.7 introduced a new ‘META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports’ file for registering auto-configurations, while maintaining backwards compatibility with registration in ‘spring.factories’. With Spring Boot 3.0 release, support for registering auto-configurations in ‘spring.factories’ has been removed in favor of the imports file.

Answer (score 0):

we are using @SpringBootApplication annotations on spring boot project main class in which they have all others annotations.
[image]